# Save user's gender and location from youtube login OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I have youtube login setup with OAuth2 and upon a successful user registration I would like to save the users gender and location in the database.

Checking the OAuth docs https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall
 you can see that you can access a users gender and location along with things like name, email and their profile picture.

Below is my code for saving a users info to the db

user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.picture = auth.info.image
      user.gender = auth.info.gender
      user.country = auth.info.locale
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save! 
      end
     end
```

but using the auth.info.USER_INFO config doesn't seem to save these values to the database. Am i missing something?

Here are the parameters my app is asking for without any scopes.
[image]

UPDATE

I got this to work by passing in an extra scope for the userinfo.profile parameter. Remember to include full urls with no commas separated by a space.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :youtube, YOUTUBE_KEY, YOUTUBE_SECRET, { :scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://gdata.youtube.com", access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: '' }
end
```

This got the following permissions
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the code where you ask for OAuth scopes? My guess is that you aren't asking for the profile scope. Check out this site:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

If you're just using the YouTube sample code, you're probably not asking for the profile scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

You can tell if you are asking for this scope or not when you hit the auth page, because the auth page will say something like:

"Google OAuth 2.0 Playground is requesting permission to:
View basic information about your account
View your name, public profile URL, and photo
View your gender and birthdate
View your country, language, and timezone"

I've attached a screenshot.[image] If you're not seeing this, look to where you are configuring your scopes and add this to the list of OAUth scopes to authorize.