# Can't save gender or Location google oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, omniauth

Thanks to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291409/save-users-gender-and-location-from-youtube-login-oauth) I have amended my scopes so now I am requesting the correct permisisons so that I can save a users gender and location to the DB.

This is my user.rb code where all the info bar gender and location are saved. After following the protocol set by auth.info.name etc neither gender or location are saved or even retrieved.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.picture = auth.info.image
      user.gender = auth.info.gender
      user.country = auth.info.locale
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save! 
      end
     end
```

here are the scopes im sending in

```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :youtube, YOUTUBE_KEY, YOUTUBE_SECRET, { :scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://gdata.youtube.com", access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: '' }
end
```

routes

```
match 'auth/youtube/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

Does anyone know the correct way to save these 2 values?

Comment: What's the gem you are using? `omniauth-google-oauth2` or `omniauth-openid`? Did you define any extra permissions or scopes in your omniauth configuration?

Comment: Hi Ashitaka, ive added the scopes to the question. These show the correct permissions when granting access from google. I am using gem 'omniauth-openid' & gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'.

Comment: Did you add that scope to the `:google_oauth2` provider? Also, what is the exact url you are using to login with Google? And finally, why are you using the `omniauth-openid` gem? If you want to login with OpenID, that's fine, but if you only want to login with Google, you don't need that gem.

Comment: Ive added the full scope and the log in url in the question above and removed the open id gem as you are right its not being used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are looking for that info in the wrong place in the omniauth hash. If you add the following line of code to the beginning of your controller action:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```

You'll be able to inspect the contents of the hash returned by the OAuth provider and see that `gender` and `locale` are located inside the `extra` key of the hash.

So, the answer here is just changing the two offending lines to:

```
user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
user.country = auth.extra.raw_info.locale
```